# php webservice for registering and login

Tags: php, mysql, web-services

I am trying to create a webservice in PHP to be able to register and login for an Android-app. I am able to register succesfully but logging in is giving me difficulty and it seems that the cause is that some variables are not fetched succesfully.

This is the function where something is going wrong:

```
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {
    print("Getting user by email and password");
    // execute query and store all results
    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    print_r("   result = ");
    print_r($result);

    // check the results
    $no_of_rows = count($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        print("     results is more than 0");
        $salt = $result['salt'];
        print("   salt = ");
        print($salt);
        echo $salt;
        $encrypted_password = $result['encrypted_password'];
        print("   encrypted password = ");
        print($encrypted_password);
        $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
        print("   hash = ");
        print($hash);

        // check if passwords match
        if($encrypted_password == $hash) {
            print_r("   encrypted password matches hash");
            // user authentication succeeded, return results
            return $result;
        }
        print_r("   passwords do not match");
    }
    else {
        print_r("   user not found");
        // user not found
        return false;
    }
}
```

postman output returns:

```
Getting user by email and password   result = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 9
            [unique_id] => 5552f5e4832e31.64783784
            [name] => blabla
            [email] => blabla@gmail.com
            [encrypted_password] => ikfU50Ryt9ostn1o68Kb2AtgN2E3Yzg4MjBiNjg1
            [salt] => 7c8820b685
            [created_at] => 2015-05-13 08:57:40
            [updated_at] => 
        )

)
     results is more than 0   salt =    encrypted password =    hash = Kp�   passwords do not match{"tag":"login","error":true,"error_msg":"Incorrect email or password!"}     destructing DB_Functionsclosing DB connectionDestructing DB_Connectclosing DB connection
```

As you can see, when I try to print the variable values, they are empty. Why is that? The query does return a result so am I doing something wrong with the variable assigning?

If the variables do not assign correctly then it makes sense that this password check fails.... **So my question is: If my suspicion is correct, then how do I assign these variables correctly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close, the solution to your problem is like this:

```
$salt = $result[0]['salt'];
print("   salt = ");
print($salt);
```

The reason for this is you've got an array of results, but there is only 1 item in the array. Because it's an array, you've still got to select the first item.